# Periodically output to browser on long operation

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, load-data-infile

I'm using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import 11M records and then the script continues with other operations. The import takes 10 minutes by which time the browser has given up (after 3 minutes) and I don't see the progress of the subsequent operations. Is there a way to output something to the browser periodically while this time consuming query is running. Phpmyadmin seems to do something like this and the browser doesn't time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out flush() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) or ob_flush() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).

Basically you generate your output (current status in this case) normally then force the server to output what is currently in the buffer.

If your operation is taking 10 minutes you will likely need to use set_time_limit($seconds) (http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), be careful you don't just set it to some big amount in case the page does hang.

If you want to output status every 10% (1 minute) you could reset the timeout for 2 minutes after each update has been flushed. This way your script will timeout if it goes beyond expected time running.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is PHP doesn't continue to the next function until it's completed the mysql query. I need it to output something to the browser while it's doing the query.

Comment: The second part of my answer answers your question then, you can set a timeout larger than 10 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I have a php timeout for 20 minutes, PHP isn't timing out. It's the browser stops waiting after 3 minutes. Once that happens I don't get any more updates to the browser.
I have other long scripts which are in a loop. With these I can periodically output something to the browser to keep it "interested"

Comment: Look at setting keep-alive parameters in your header.

With all this said, I really think none of this is the way to go. 

For such a long operation you should be running it in a background process on the server and then on your page use javascript to poll the status of your job. I don't use any of the web interfaces like phpmyadmin but I would be very surprised if they don't run them in the background and just poll for the status. 

I presume this is a tool for one or very few people and so you can probably get by this way but it is in no way scalable.

Comment: Yes, that's a great idea. I can get javascript to poll something to keep the browser alive so I'll see the rest of the output. It's a very complicated database conversion script with many stages. Eventually it'll run on a cron job without output but for now we need to see the output as it progresses. Thanks for your help.