# Firefox says the connection was reset but the script is running

Tags: php, firefox

I get this message(Screenshot below. The browser shows loading for almost 5-6 minutes and then it shows this.) while I run a PHP script which makes multiple API calls and DB updates but I can see that the script is still running by checking its effects(like it processed only 40 records when I see the message and when I check again I can see that the script processed 45 records and it keeps increasing.)

What can cause this problem?

Is it possible to make the browser stay loading until the script finish executing?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to execute in cli instead of browser ?

Comment: You hit a network timeout. If you have scripts, that run for more than a few seconds, you should probably execute those from the server CLI or using a cron job

Comment: You could peridically flush some data to the browser to prevent the timeout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264324/periodically-output-to-browser-on-long-operation

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method: this is the solution for me

```
<?php  
ob_end_clean();  
header("Connection: close"); 
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size"); 
?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify how this solves the question being asked?